# UPDATE INNER JOIN unknown column in on clause

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I know there are already some answers to this question but none of them seem to work for me.

Basically, i've got tasks which are nothing more than presets sheduled over time : i want to update the tasks date when reaching the deadlines ; also when i reach a deadline, i need to update the values of the components table according to the preset values.

I successfully made the query to update the deadlines which looks like this :

```
UPDATE tasks

    SET tasks.start_date = DATE_ADD(
    tasks.start_date, INTERVAL tasks.frequency SECOND
    )

    WHERE tasks.start_date <= CURRENT_DATE AND tasks.hour <= CURRENT_TIME
```

When I try update the components rows at the same time as the deadlines i can't get it to work. My query looks like this :

```
    UPDATE tasks,components 

    INNER JOIN presets ON presets.id = tasks.id_preset
    INNER JOIN preset_values ON preset_values.id_preset = presets.id
    INNER JOIN preset_values AS pv2 ON pv2.serial_number = 
    components.serial_number 

    SET tasks.start_date = DATE_ADD(
    tasks.start_date, INTERVAL tasks.frequency SECOND
    ),
    components.value = pv2.value,
    components.state = pv2.on_off

    WHERE tasks.start_date <= CURRENT_DATE AND tasks.hour <= CURRENT_TIME
```

The message error I get is :
MySQL said: Documentation

## 1054 - Unknown column 'tasks.id_preset' in 'on clause'

can you help me to get this query to work ? thank you

components table : https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOZX8.png

presets table : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs7yO.png

preset_values table : https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZkcm.png

tasks table : https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qSEe.png

**EDIT** : after thinking twice I opted for two separate update queries. It currently looks like this. If anyone has a single update solution I'll be glad to use it if it's better performance wise. Otherwise I'll stick to this solution for the moment. Thank you all for your kind help.

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE
        components AS c1
    INNER JOIN preset_values AS pv1
    ON
        pv1.serial_number = c1.serial_number
    INNER JOIN tasks AS t1
    ON
        t1.id_preset = pv1.id_preset
    SET
        c1.value = pv1.value,
        c1.state = pv1.on_off
    WHERE
        t1.start_date <= CURRENT_DATE AND t1.hour <= CURRENT_TIME AND t1.on_off=1;
    UPDATE
        tasks
    SET
        tasks.start_date = DATE_ADD(
            tasks.start_date,
            INTERVAL tasks.frequency SECOND
        )
    WHERE
        tasks.start_date <= CURRENT_DATE AND tasks.hour <= CURRENT_TIME AND t1.on_off=1 ;
END
```

Comment: What is the current error message?

Comment: The error `unknown column in on clause` should tell you all. Since you do not expose your table structures, nobody can guess which of the 6 field names in your on clauses are wrong or not. Usually the error message is: "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column **'column_name'** in 'on clause'"

Comment: I updated my question.I apologize that it was very unclear in the first place. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really do need a cross join for some reason (extremely unlikely), you should use the `CROSS JOIN` clause or swap the comma-separated tables into `components, tasks`. Your query

```
UPDATE tasks,components INNER JOIN presets ON presets.id = tasks.id_preset ...
```

means

```
UPDATE tasks, (components INNER JOIN presets ON presets.id = tasks.id_preset) ...
```

Obviously there is no `tasks.id_preset` in `components INNER JOIN presets ON presets.id = tasks.id_preset`

However, a cross join would mean that each of your filtered explicit joined rows  are combined with each row of the table `components`. The last each row would perform a

```
SET
components.value = pv2.value,
components.state = pv2.on_off
```

I do not believe that this is anyhow intended. Think twice if this **operation on the Cartesian product** is actually what you want.

There is a `serial_number` in `components`, so you most likely want

```
UPDATE     tasks
INNER JOIN presets       ON presets.id               = tasks.id_preset
INNER JOIN preset_values ON preset_values.id_preset  = presets.id
INNER_JOIN components    ON components.serial_number = preset_values.serial_number 

SET ...
```

Comment: After thinking twice I opted for doing two separate update queries. I updated my post. Thank you for your help. Indeed what i was doing wasn't necessary for what i needed.

Comment: @MatthieuLormeau In general do a SELECT * instead of an UPDATE and see what you get. Then transform into UPDATE setting the desired fields/values.

Answer (score 0):

you need to connect `tasks` and `components` on where clause. now, they are cross joined.